# RにCSVデータをインポートする際の日付型の処理について

Tags: r

#### 問題点

Rでread.csvを行う際、日付型のカラムを数値型に変換してインポートをしたいと思い、csvの元になっているSpreadsheetで該当カラムを数値型でフォーマットするも、Rにインポートすると文字型(chr)扱いになってしまう。

#### 試してみたこと

- Spreadsheet上で新しく別カラムを挿入し、日付型のカラムを数値に変換したものを値ばりしてみるも同様の結果
- 文字列になっているカラム(データとしては数値型日付が入っている状態)についてR内でas.numericしてみると全てNAになってしまう

#### 教えていただきたいこと

Spreadsheet上で事前にどのような処理を行えばCSVをインポートした時点で該当カラムが数値型入稿になるか

Comment: `read.csv()` の読み込みでは基本的に数値でないものが文字列 (4.0 より前は `factor`) になります. spreadsheet (エクセルのこと?) ではなくテキストエディタでcsvを開いて実際にどのような値が入力されているか確認してください

Answer (score 1):

`readr`パッケージの`read_csv`を使えば良いかと思います。

```
# データ読み込み
data <- read_csv('filepath.csv')

# カラムの型確認
str(data)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！おかげさまでうまく読み込みできました。お礼が遅くなり失礼いたしました。